# IBM Worklight 6.0 - Google maps fail to load while retrieving directions

Tags: google-maps, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using Google API v3 for "directions to here". However, the maps are not getting loaded properly. I am getting no error in logs.

When the page loads, I do the following:

```
var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat(), start.lng());
var endPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(end.latitude), parseFloat(end.longitude));
var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
    },
    center: endPoint
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("branchLocatorSiteMapCanvas"), mapOptions);
$r.currentPage.map = map;

$page.off('pageshow').on('pageshow', function () {
    // Suitable for V3 and fix for map div is not rendered
    if ($r.currentPage.map) {
        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            google.maps.event.trigger($r.currentPage.map, 'resize');
            if (endPoint) {
               $r.currentPage.map.setCenter(endPoint);
            }
            else if (startPoint) {
               $r.currentPage.map.setCenter(startPoint);
            }

            window.clearTimeout(timer);
        }, 400);
    }
});

if ($r.currentPage.map) {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce($r.currentPage.map, 'idle', function () {
        // Do something only the first time the map is loaded
        google.maps.event.trigger($r.currentPage.map, 'resize');
                  $r.currentPage.map.setCenter(endPoint);
    });
```

I use this snippet for Direction Service and Rendering.

```
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you?  What does your code look like?

Comment: What is your Worklight version? Which mobile environment are you testing this on? What errors do you get when testing?

Comment: I am using Worklight version 6.0. The devices I am using are BB10, Android and iOS7. I am not getting any error in code. It happens at times with a moderate WiFI area.

Comment: I am using Google API v3. For Direction Service and rendering, I am calling var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try it with your code example, but you can take this simpler demo project to see how to make it work in a Worklight 6.0.0.2-based app: [Google Maps Directions Demo project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5v8yzvjml4wl21/GoogleMapsDirections.zip).

The demo project is based [on this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) via the Google Maps documentation.

End result is:
[image]

JavaScript portion of the app:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function wlCommonInit(){
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            disableDefaultUI: false,
            center: chicago
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using the same code. Still see the issue  - var request = {
            origin: startPoint,
            destination: endPoint,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });